# I'm trying to loop through a CSV file in PHP and add the returned data into a mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Here is the PHP / xAjax function we are calling when we click a submit CSV button, I can get a response at the end of the function using a pop up modal that has the correct data but it doesn't get inserted into our database. I want to know why i can return data on the page but once I try to send it to mysql there is no response. There is also HTML code and Javascript involved but I believe there are no issues with those.

```
$fileHandle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
// Skips Headers in csv file
fgets($fileHandle);
//Loop through the CSV rows.
while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    //Print out my column data.
    $orderFormData['testdata1'] = $row[0];
    if(strlen($orderFormData['testdata1']) == '' ){
        $VerifyStatus = 'Missing data in CSV file, please take a look for empty cells.';
    }  

    $orderFormData['testdata2'] = $row[1];
    if(strlen($orderFormData['testdata2']) == '' ){
        $VerifyStatus = 'Missing data in CSV file, please take a look for empty cells.';
    }

    $orderFormData['testdata3'] = $row[2];
    if(strlen($orderFormData['testdata3']) == '' ){
        $VerifyStatus = 'Missing data in CSV file, please take a look for empty cells.';
    }
    
    $orderFormData['testdata4'] = $row[3];
    if(strlen($orderFormData['testdata4']) == '' ){
        $VerifyStatus = 'Missing data in CSV file, please take a look for empty cells.';
    }
    
    //  Rob  //

    $orderFormData['Note'] = preg_replace('/[^\da-z \-,@$%&()_+=*#?.]/i', '', $orderFormData['Note']);

    if(strlen($contactFormData['testdata5']) == '' ){
        $VerifyStatus = 'Please enter a company contact so that we can get in touch if there are any issues with your order!';
    }

    $DebugText .= "<BR>".$VerifyStatus;
    if ($VerifyStatus == 'OK') {
        $query = "INSERT INTO testtable set ".
                "Status = \"Open\", ".
                "Source = \"testportal\", ".
                "data1 = \"".$orderFormData['testdata1']."\",".
                "data2 = \"".$orderFormData['testdata2']."\",".
                "data3 = \"".$orderFormData['testdata3']."\",".
                "RecordDate= \"".$q_time."\"";
        $DebugText.= "<BR>".$query;
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'], $query);
        if (!$result){
            $objResponse->addScript('swal("Oops...", "'.$VerifyStatus.'", "error");');
        };
        $rows_affected=mysql_affected_rows();
        $DebugText.= "<BR>rows affected: ".$rows_affected;
        if($rows_affected>0){
            $objResponse->addScript('Swal("Order Recieved", "Check orders page for updates!");');
            $objResponse->addScript('clearForms();');
        }
    } else{
        $objResponse->addScript('swal("Oops...", "'.$VerifyStatus.'", "error");');
    }
    return $objResponse->getXML();
}
```

Comment: Good 'eavens, use single quotes inside a double quoted literal and maybe this will be readabale without all the blizard of escaping

Comment: Building a query like that also leaves you open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Echo'ing out $query and trying to run it against the database will also help.

Comment: Your query is executed inside `if ($VerifyStatus == 'OK') {` but I dont see anywhere where you set `$VerifyStatus = 'OK`

Answer (score 1):

You never set `$VerifyStatus` to `'OK'`, it should be done just after the While starts then, if you find no errors that will set it to something else the database query will run

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $VerifyStatus = 'OK';
```